# ElasticSearch Error: MapperParsingException failed to parse

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

I am trying to integrate MYSQL in ElasticSearch On windows 7 from this [link](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc)

I have completed the following steps:

1:

> Download & Unzip in C Directory
>   https://download.elasticsearch.org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-1.3.4.zip

2:

> Run this command on CMD  ./bin/plugin --install jdbc --url
>   http://xbib.org/repository/org/xbib/elasticsearch/plugin/elasticsearch-river-jdbc/1.3.4.4/elasticsearch-river-jdbc-1.3.4.4-plugin.zip

3:

> Download MYSQL Connector mysql-connector-java-5.1.33.zip from MYSQL website.
>
> Unzip and copy mysql-connector-java-5.1.33-bin.jar file.
>
> Place it into C:\elasticsearch-1.3.4\plugins\jdbc

I have checked now there are two files in plugins directory

- elasticsearch-river-jdbc-1.3.4.4.jar
- mysql-connector-java-5.1.33-bin

Now I tried to execute this command on CMD and I got error

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/jdbc-1.3.4.4-d2e33c3/_meta' -d '{
    "type" : "jdbc",
    "jdbc" : {
        "url" : "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test",
        "user" : "root",
        "password" : "pass",
        "sql" : "select * from abc"
    }
}'
```

---

```
{
  "error": "MapperParsingException[failed to parse]; nested: JsonParseException[Unexpected character (''' (code 39)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: [B@3cf756; line: 1, column:2]]; ",
  "status": 400
}
```

---

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: type; Host not found

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: :; No data record of requested type

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: jdbc,jdbc; No data record of requested type

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: :; No data record of requested type

curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched brace at pos 5

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: :; No data record of requested type

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: jdbc:mysql:; No data record of requested type

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: :; No data record of requested type

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: root,password; No data record of requested typ
e
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: :; No data record of requested type

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: pass,sql; No data record of requested type

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: :; No data record of requested type

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: select * from abc; No data record of requested type
```

> MYSQL(5.5.37) Database (test) contains just one table (abc) with two columns
>   id(pk) and address (varchar)

I am using this **jdbc-1.3.4.4-d2e33c3** name as jdbc driver. I get this name from this link.

```
http://localhost:9200/_nodes?settings=true&pretty=true
```

I have searched on it but cannot found any issue like this related to mysql integration.

My Question is anything still missing or I am doing wrong setup.?

Answer (score 5):

On Windows curls acts differently. Try using
`curl -XPUT "http://127.0.0.1:9200/index/type/id" -d "{ """attribute""" : """name""" }".`Try with those triple  quotes

Comment: thanks @atkawa7. i wonder why curl uses triple quotes. i also tried with \" and it worked (in windows 7 64 bit)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Sense (Beta)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sense-beta/lhjgkmllcaadmopgmanpapmpjgmfcfig) extension of Google Chrome. It has very nice features like auto-complete, syntax checking, syntax highlighting, keyboard shortcuts, and history.

[Marvel](http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/marvel) is another option. a complete developer-free ES management console. it is included a newer version of Sense, but it's not free for production nodes and has features that this question didn't ask

Answer (score 0):

Sure,on windows curl acts different..
Mine is windows 7 64bit os
This worked for me..

> curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/1" -d "{""user"":""Rahul A Pawar"", ""message"":""it was fun""}"

-Use double quotes for key:value.

Answer (score 0):

And yes, if your value contains a space, remember it to escape it with backslash (\ ). And what """ means, you are escaping one double-quote with another double-quote leaving effectively two to be processed.
It all boils down to escaping chars in a Windows way.

Comment: Correction: Instead of \ please use " above to escape space.