# JSON Parse Exception when creating Index Template

Tags: json, powershell, curl, elasticsearch, logstash

I'm using Powershell (via Cmder) along with `curl` (GoW) to create an index template in elasticsearch.

Here's my curl:

```
curl -XPUT http://myAddress:9200/_template/logstash_per_iis -u user:password -d' 
{
    "template" : "logstash*",
    "mappings" : {
      "iis" : {
        "properties" : {
            "response":{"type":"int"},
            "site":{"type":"ip"},
            "supresponse":{"type":"int"},
            "time_taken":{"type":"int"},
            "clientHost":{"type":"ip"},
            "port":{"type":"int"},
            "scstatus":{"type":"int"}
        }
      }
    }
}
'
```

Here's the response from ES:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "failed to parse template source"
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "failed to parse template source",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "json_parse_exception",
      "reason": "Unrecognized token 'logstash': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: [B@38a6a400; line: 3, column: 25]"
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

ES is stating a `json_parse_exception`, however, I cannot figure out where my JSON package is invalid.

What is wrong with my JSON or am I doing something else incorrectly?

Comment: It's weird, I could execute that exact curl command (after replacing `myAddress` with `localhost`)  on both ES 1.x and ES 2.x clusters without any problem (on MacOS).

Comment: @Val, I should have noted more explicitly that I'm on windows. Looks like the answer is I needed """ vs ". Thanks for your time, though. Much appreciated.

Comment: No prob, I'll leave my comment for the Mac folks landing on this question ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out curl on windows needs """ instead of just ".

Found the answer from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27761856/899048

So, my curl ends up looking like this:..

```
curl -XPUT http://myAddress:9200/_template/logstash_per_iis -u user:password -d' 
{
    """template""" : """logstash*"""
    """mappings""" : {
      """iis""" : {
          """response""":{"""type""":"""int"""},
          """site""":{"""type""":"""ip"""},
          """supresponse""":{"""type""":"""int"""},
          """time_taken""":{"""type""":"""int"""},
          """clientHost""":{"""type""":"""ip"""},
          """port""":{"""type""":"""int"""},
          """scstatus""":{"""type""":"""int"""}
      }
    }
}
'
```

Looks horrible, but it worked.

Comment: One of the comments on that question mentions \", which works for me and looks better.